# Regarding the fruit punch Gatorade question

Tags: discussion

My fruit punch Gatorade question was closed as off-topic.  If I remove the bit about cancer would my question then be on-topic?

Also, not sure what the moderator, rumtscho, meant by "automatically safe by their standard" - for example, cigarettes and liquor are sold, with warning labels, and are known to be linked to cancers and other health issues.  So, unsafe foods are being sold everyday (not totally sure if cigarette is a "food", but you get the idea ... )

Just wondering if I should stop drinking my favorite sports drink, given this new warning label - "genetically engineered" feels like sugarcoating some links to health issues ...

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Food safety is short-term consequences, health is long-term. Unless you think that the Gatorade label means you might be seriously ill within hours or days of drinking it, this is not a food safety question.

You're right, cigarettes are not food, nothing to do with this. (And their issues are mostly long-term health, not short-term safety.)

And this:

> ...given this new warning label - "genetically engineered" feels like sugarcoating some links to health issues

Health is [explicitly off-topic here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

If your questions are about what you should and shouldn't eat, this isn't the site for you.